# Consume .txt files in an express app deployed as a Netlify Serverless Function

Tags: express, serverless, netlify

I'm trying to deploy an express app to production using netlify lambda. I keep getting this error in the deployment `Error: Can't resolve './files/auth0_ss_token_filename.txt'` Is there a plugin for this or what a good workaround. Thanks

I have tried using a plugin `@netlify/plugin-functions-core` but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;DR, you need to add the following to your `netlify.toml`:

```ini
[functions]
  included_files = ["path-to-file-relative-to-project-root"]
```

Actual answer:

There's no workaround needed. Netlify provides a built-in feature to handle this, you can read about it here: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/08/12/how-to-include-files-in-netlify-serverless-functions/

Comment: I have this in my `netlify.toml`

[functions]
  included_files = ["./src/files/**.txt"]

However I dont see any .txt file added to the functions directory when i build locally with this command `netlify-lambda build src`

Comment: `netlify lambda` has been deprecated for a long time now. I don't think it supports that peoperty. Use Netlify CLI.